Solving differential equations with integrals
I have a differential equation where the rate of change of a function at a point depends on the convolution of the entire function with a gaussian function:
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(t, x) = f(t, x) + \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(y - x)^2} f(t, y)dy$$
Given an initial function $f(0, -)$, I would like to evaluate $f(t, x)$ for any given $t$ and $x$ to an arbitrary precision. How would I do this?

Perhaps Fredholm equations can help you in a fruitful direction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation

Does $f$ admit a Fourier transform? That may be an idea too to start.

Taking the Fourier transform of the equation in $x$ and using the convolution rule $\mathcal F[g\ast h] = \hat g \hat h$ gives
$$
\frac \partial {\partial t} \hat f(t,\omega) = \hat f(t,\omega) + \hat f(t,\omega) \mathcal F[e^{-x^2}] = \hat f(t,\omega)[1 + \sqrt \pi e^{-\omega^2/4}].
$$
For each fixed $\omega$, this is a linear ODE in $t$, with solution
$$
\hat f(t,\omega) = \hat f(0,\omega) \exp[t(1+\sqrt\pi e^{-\omega^2/4})].
$$
This expression is not so satisfactory, because $\exp[t(1+\sqrt\pi e^{-\omega^2/4})]$ does not go to zero as $|\omega|\to \infty$, so you'd (apparently) need some decay for $\hat f(0,\omega)$ to be able to compute the inverse Fourier transform.
To get a better expression, we rearrange a bit to write
$$
\hat f(t,\omega) =  e^t \hat f(0,\omega) +  e^t \hat f(0,\omega) ( \exp[t \sqrt\pi e^{-\omega^2/4}] - 1). 
$$
Then we take the inverse transform and use the convolution rule again to write
$$
f(t,x) = e^t \left[f(0,x) +  f(0,x) \ast \mathcal F^{-1}(\exp[t \sqrt \pi e^{-\omega^2/4}] - 1)\right]
$$
where the convolution is in $x$. You can compute this expression numerically using your favorite inverse Fourier transform implementation.

Let's apply the Fourier Transform (FT) on both sides with respect to $x$:
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\hat f(t,\kappa)=\hat f(t,\kappa)+\widehat{\left[e^{-x^2}\right]}(\kappa)\cdot \hat f(t,\kappa)=\left(1+\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\kappa^2}{4}}}{\sqrt 2}\right)\hat f(t,\kappa),$$
Notice that the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x-y)^2}f(t,y)\,\mathrm dy\sim \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x-y)\Phi(y)\,\mathrm dy$$
is a convolution and therefore its FT with respect to $x$ is the product of the transform of each of these two,
$\hat\varphi(\kappa)\cdot\hat\Phi(\kappa)$ .
Now we can proceed by separating variables:
$$\int\dfrac{\mathrm d\hat f(t,\kappa)}{\hat f(t,\kappa)}=\left(1+\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\kappa^2}{4}}}{\sqrt 2}\right)\int\mathrm dt\implies \hat f(t,\kappa)=C\exp\left[\left(1+\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\kappa^2}{4}}}{\sqrt 2}\right)t\right]$$
The initial condition for the pair $(t,x)$ was that the function would be $f(0,x)$. Therefore, by applying the FT with respect to $x$ on it we can find it expressed in terms of the pair $(t,\kappa)$: $\hat f(0,\kappa)$. Hence, we find the the constant of integration depends on $\kappa$ too and it is $C=\hat f(0,\kappa)$:
$$\hat f(t,\kappa)=\hat f(0,\kappa)\exp\left[\left(1+\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\kappa^2}{4}}}{\sqrt 2}\right)t\right]$$
Finally, we can now apply the inverse FT in order to obtain the solution. For that we'll employ yet again the convolution theorem in order to leave the result in terms of the initial function:
$$f(t,x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(0,x-y)\,\mathscr F^{-1}\!\!\left\{\exp\left[\left(1+\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\kappa^2}{4}}}{\sqrt 2}\right)t\right]\right\}(y)\,\mathrm dy$$
where
$$\mathscr F^{-1}\!\!\left\{\exp\left[\left(1+\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\kappa^2}{4}}}{\sqrt 2}\right)t\right]\right\}(y)=\dfrac{e^t}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left[\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\kappa^2}{4}}}{\sqrt 2}t+i\kappa y\right]\,\mathrm d\kappa$$
And thus we finally have
$$f(t,x)=\dfrac{e^t}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(0,x-y) \exp\left[\dfrac{e^{-\frac{\kappa^2}{4}}}{\sqrt 2}t+i\kappa y\right]\,\mathrm d\kappa\,\mathrm dy$$
